# How to use constructor injection for android ViewModels with Toothpick

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-viewmodel, toothpick-di

I want to use constructor injection for my view models

```kotlin
@InjectConstructor
class SomeViewModel(private val dependency: SomeDependency) : ViewModel() { ... }
```

It seems possible with custom view model factory `subScope.installViewModelBinding<VM>(fragment, factory)`
but I haven't figured out yet how can I do it in convenient way, any suggestions?